# How to render according to if syntax in view file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to render only the view of the post with number string input according to if syntax.

But my code gets all the posts.

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @fleamarkets.each do |x| %> // @fleamarket == Fleamarket.all
  <% if x.number == '1' %>
    <%= render 'fleamarkets/card1', :x => x %>
  <% elsif x.number == '2' %>
    <%= render 'fleamarkets/card2', :x => x %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'fleamarkets/card3', :x => x %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**_card1.html.erb**

```
<h4 class="card-title" style="text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid black;"><%= x.title %></h4>
```

Comment: So, whats the problem you have now?

Comment: The problem you are having is not really clear.  You are looping through all flea markets, so you will end up showing all no matter how you are filtering the view. Then I guess you show a card depending on which `number`, so is it properly showing the correct card based on your conditional for each flea market?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... Also, I notice you are comparing "number" to `'1'` as a **string** (you have quotes around it). It's very possible you need to do this instead for each if statement: `if x.number == 1` (notice theres no quotes)

```
<% @fleamarkets.each do |x| %>
  <% if x.number == '1' %>
    <%= render partial: 'fleamarkets/card1', locals: {x: x} %>
  <% elsif x.number == '2' %>
    <%= render partial: 'fleamarkets/card2', locals: {x: x} %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render partial: 'fleamarkets/card3', locals: {x: x} %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: AFAIK, `locals` only work with the combination `partial` keyword

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the if statement and replace with:

```
<%= render "fleamarkets/card#{x.number}", x: x %>
```

Comment: What if there is no such partial? What if the number `675`?

Comment: This should probably be validated on the model. It depends on their specific use-case.